# AngularJs Error - Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs, i have seen enough posts for a similar question but haven't found solution for my problem. I am using Angular 1.4.5

app.js (Omitted additional code like Routes and interceptors):

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'authControllers', 'authServices']);
var authControllers = angular.module('authControllers', []);
var authServices = angular.module('authServices', []);
```

authControllers.js:

```
authControllers.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService',
function authCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService) {
  //Admin User Controller (login, logout)
  $scope.logIn = function logIn(username, password) {
    if (username !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
      UserService.logIn(username, password).success(function(data) {
        AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;
        $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
        $location.path("/");
      }).error(function(status, data) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
  $scope.logout = function logout() {
    if (AuthenticationService.isLogged) {
      AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
      delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
      $location.path("/");
    }
  }
}
]);
```

authServices.js:

```
authServices.factory('AuthenticationService',function() {
  var auth = {
    isLogged: false
  }
  return auth;
});
```

Index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-ng-controller="authCtrl">
       <!-- data-ng-controller="authCtrl" -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular Restful Auth</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ng-href="#/">Home</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-show="token"><a ng-href="#/me">Me</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-hide="token"><a ng-href="#/signin">Signin</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-hide="token"><a ng-href="#/signup">Signup</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-show="token"><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view="">
    </div> <!-- /container -->    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/authentication/authControllers.js"></script>
<script src="/js/authentication/authServices.js"></script>
</body>
```

Getting
Uncaught Error: [[$injector:unpr]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthenticationServiceProvider%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthenticationServiceProvider%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService)

Please let me know what's the mistake i am doing.

Comment: Did you include authController.js and authServices.js in your Index.html?

Comment: Included app.js that has references to my authControllers.js and authServices.js. Do i have to include both of them as well ?

Comment: Yep unless you are using some lazy loading library.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Can you update your original post to show what you have added?

Comment: Can you replace `authServices` in `authServices.js` with `angular.module('authServices')` and do the same for `authControllers`?

Comment: So it would be `angular.module('authServices').factory(...`

Comment: Yes not including the scripts was the problem. Previously i am having other syntax error because of which the error still showed up even though scripts were included, when i solved it its working. Thank you very much !

Comment: If you can write the same as an answer, i can mark it as answer and the thread would be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting down answer as discussed in comments:

The problem was not including the modular js files in index.html

Example:

```
<script src="/js/authControllers.js"></script>
<script src="/js/authServices.js"></script>
```